# Range of Geomagnetic Levels

Tags: geomagnetism

What would the range of geomagnetic levels need to be so that Utica is within the oval of the Aurora Borealis while Albany is not?

Comment: Umm, the auroral oval is usually several degrees of latitude wide, i.e., hundreds to thousands of miles across.  You cannot have Utica within the oval while Albany is outside of it.